How to find Base-line of Curved Text?
Attached is a picture with curved lines, how can you find the Baseline of the text?

The goal is to get lines like I drew by hand in the following picture:

I tried the following code, but letters like g p q y and similar break the line.
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

src = cv.imread("boston_cooking_a.jpg", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
src = cv.adaptiveThreshold(src=src, maxValue=255, blockSize=55, C=11, thresholdType=cv.THRESH_BINARY, adaptiveMethod=cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C)
src = cv.dilate(src, cv.getStructuringElement(ksize=(3, 3), shape=cv.MORPH_RECT))
src = cv.erode(src, cv.getStructuringElement(ksize=(50, 3), shape=cv.MORPH_RECT))
src = cv.Sobel(src, ddepth=0, dx=0, dy=1, ksize=5)
cv.imwrite("test.jpg", src)
cv.imshow("src", src)
cv.waitKey(0)


EDIT:
Attached is another image to test your answer on, so we can make sure the answer doesn't suffer from "overfitting" to a single image.


let's help this along... you should briefly review academic literature on existing approaches to this.

you can use vision model for this,  unless it's for homework on image processing class

or you can have transformation for every letter, placing dot under each letter in desired place and in the end you can link all dots, you will have to maintain some "dictionary" letter_place->dot_place, since there are 26 letters lower+upper, 10 digits and commas etc. it's possible to do it

I suggest to use the opencv drawing functions: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html. This requires the determination of the coordinates of each text character.

@SudoKoach I don't think the drawing itself is the issue here.

The issue is the determination of the coordinates of each individual text character in order to draw a continuous (unbroken) curved baseline.

How about applying neural nets? https://github.com/ychensu/LRANet

or https://dhlab-epfl.github.io/dhSegment/

How slow can the algorithm be? lmao

@Canbach Up to 10 seconds per page.

you should look for book scanners, made for old and fragile books. they may be constructed from DSLR cameras and a movable plexiglass "page flattener".

I found an approach which is a possibility to find your lines in „pure“ opencv. The  suggested solution is not perfect, but demonstrates a first direction.
Maybe you should use pytesseract to follow up your overall goal ?
In general the suggested solution below is quite
sensitive to the parameters of the first filter A.
The basics pseudo code steps are:

A) apply filters to merge letters to words
B) select contours of words (filter by: ratio heights vs widths , area size)
C) get random points from word-contours using gaussian distribution and the center point centroid of contour
D) use linear regression to find middle line of word-contours
E) merge all word-contours which are neighbors to line-contours (outer middle line points are close together)
F) do polynomial regression 2nd order to estimate middle line of line-contours
G) write the found merged lines from our estimaded group line

The main output for example 2 shows robust output but still has some artifacts from step 1 merge all letter to words.

import cv2
import math
import uuid
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

def resizeImageByPercentage(img,scalePercent = 60):
    width = int(img.shape[1] * scalePercent / 100)
    height = int(img.shape[0] * scalePercent / 100)
    dim = (width, height)
    # resize image
    return cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

def calcMedianContourWithAndHeigh(contourList):
    hs = list()
    ws = list()
    for cnt in contourList:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        ws.append(w)
        hs.append(h)
    return np.median(ws),np.median(hs)

def calcCentroid(contour):
    houghMoments = cv2.moments(contour)
    # calculate x,y coordinate of centroid
    if houghMoments["m00"] != 0: #case no contour could be calculated
        cX = int(houghMoments["m10"] / houghMoments["m00"])
        cY = int(houghMoments["m01"] / houghMoments["m00"])
    else:
    # set values as what you need in the situation
        cX, cY = -1, -1
    return cX,cY

def applyDilateImgFilter(img,kernelSize= 3,iterations=1):
    img_bin = 255 - img #invert
    kernel = np.ones((kernelSize,kernelSize),np.uint8)
    img_dilated = cv2.dilate(img_bin, kernel, iterations = iterations)
    return (255- img_dilated) #invert back

def randomColor():
    return tuple(np.random.randint(0, 255, 3).tolist())

def drawGaussianValuesInsideRange(start, end, center, stdDev, amountValues):
    values = []
    if center < 0:
        return values
    if start > end:
        return values
    while len(values) < amountValues:
        valueListPotencial = np.random.normal(center, stdDev, amountValues)
        valueListFiltered = [value for value in valueListPotencial if start <= value <= end]
        values.extend(valueListFiltered)
    return values[:amountValues]

def drawRandomPointsInPolygon(amountPoints, cntFactObj):
    pointList = list()
    if not isinstance(cntFactObj, ContourFacts):
        return pointList
    #we calc basic parameter from random point selection
    horizontalStart = cntFactObj.x
    horizontalEnd = cntFactObj.x + cntFactObj.w
    verticalStart = cntFactObj.y
    verticalEnd = cntFactObj.y + cntFactObj.h  
    #calc std deviation connected to length and ratio
    horitonalStdDeviation = 1 / cntFactObj.ratioHeightoWidth * (horizontalEnd-horizontalStart)
    verticalStdDeviation = 1 / cntFactObj.ratioHeightoWidth * (verticalEnd-verticalStart)
    while len(pointList)<amountPoints:
        if cntFactObj.centoird[0] < 0 or cntFactObj.centoird[1] < 0:
            return pointList
        drawXValues = drawGaussianValuesInsideRange(horizontalStart, horizontalEnd, cntFactObj.centoird[0],
                                          horitonalStdDeviation, amountPoints)
        drawYValues = drawGaussianValuesInsideRange(verticalStart, verticalEnd, cntFactObj.centoird[1], 
                                         verticalStdDeviation, amountPoints)
        #we create the points and check if they are inside the polygon
        for i in range(0,len(drawXValues)):
            #create points
            point = (drawXValues[i],drawYValues[i])
            # check if the point is inside the polygon
            if cv2.pointPolygonTest(cntFactObj.contour, point, False) > 0:
                pointList.append(point)
    return pointList[:amountPoints]

def drawCountourOn(img,contours,color=None):
    imgContour = img.copy()
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        if color is None:
            color = randomColor()
        cv2.drawContours(imgContour, contours, i, color, 2)
    return imgContour

DEBUGMODE = True
fileIn = "bZzzEeCU.jpg"#"269aSnEM.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(fileIn)

## A) apply filters to merge letters to words
# prepare img load
imgGrey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#gaussian filter
imgGaussianBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGrey,(3,3),1)
#make binary img, black and white via filter
_, imgBinThres = cv2.threshold(imgGaussianBlur, 140, 230, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
if DEBUGMODE:
    cv2.imwrite("img01bw.jpg",resizeImageByPercentage(imgBinThres,30))

## 3 steps merged by helper class ContourFacts
## B) select contours of words (filter by: ratio heights vs widths , area size)
## C) get random points from wordcontours with gaussian distribution and center point centroid of contour
## D) use linear regression to find middle line of wordcontours

#apply dilate filter to merge letter to words
imgDilated = applyDilateImgFilter(imgBinThres,5,3)
if DEBUGMODE:
    cv2.imwrite("img02dilated.jpg",resizeImageByPercentage(imgDilated,30))

# detect contours
contourList, _ = cv2.findContours(imgDilated, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
if DEBUGMODE:
    imgContour = drawCountourOn(img,contourList)
    cv2.imwrite("img03contourAll.jpg",resizeImageByPercentage(imgContour,30))
    
#do a selection of contours by rule
#A) ratio h vs w
#B) area size
mediaWordWidth, medianWordHigh = calcMedianContourWithAndHeigh(contourList)
print("median word width: ", mediaWordWidth)
print("median word high: ", medianWordHigh)
contourSelectedByRatio=list()
#we calc for every contour ratio h vs w
ratioThresholdHeightToWidth = 1.1 #thresold ratio should be a least be 1 to 1
# e.g word to -->  10 pixel / 13 pixel

#helper class for contour atrributess
class ContourFacts:
    def __init__(self,contour):
        if contour is None:
            return
        self.uid = uuid.uuid4()
        (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        self.minRect = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
        self.angle = self.minRect[-1]
        _, (rectWidth, rectHeight), _ = self.minRect
        self.minRectArea = rectWidth * rectHeight
        self.ratioHeightoWidth = self.h / self.w
        self.contour = contour
        self.centoird = calcCentroid(contour)
        self.randomPoinsInCnt = self.DrawRandomPoints()
        if len(self.randomPoinsInCnt) > 0:
            (self.bottomSlope, self.bottomIntercept) = self.EstimateCenterLineViaLinearReg()
            self.bottomMinX = min([x for x,y in self.randomPoinsInCnt])
            self.bottomMaxX = max([x for x,y in self.randomPoinsInCnt])

    def EstimateCenterLineViaLinearReg(self):
        if self.contour is None:
            return (0,0)
        slope = 0
        intercept = 0
        #model = slope (x) + intercept
        xValues = [x for x,y in self.randomPoinsInCnt]
        yValues = [y for x,y in self.randomPoinsInCnt]
        if len(xValues) < 2:
            return (0,0)
        elif len(xValues) ==2:
            #we calc a line with 2 points
            # y = m*x + b
            deltaX = xValues[1]-xValues[0]
            if deltaX == 0:
                return (0,0)
            slope = (yValues[1]-yValues[0])/(deltaX)
            intercept = yValues[0] - (slope*xValues[0])
        else:
            #normal linear regression above 2 points
            slope, intercept, r, p, std_err = stats.linregress(xValues, yValues)
        #TODO check std_err
        return slope, intercept
    
    def DrawRandomPoints(self,pointFactor=2):
        pointList = list()
        #calc area to amount point relation  -> bigger area more points
        amountPointsNeeded = int(self.minRectArea/pointFactor)
        pointList = drawRandomPointsInPolygon(amountPointsNeeded,self)
        return pointList
    
    def GetCenterLineLeftCorner(self):
        if self.contour is None or len(self.randomPoinsInCnt) == 0:
            return (0,0)    
        # calc via  y = m*x + b with min
        return (int(self.bottomMinX), int(self.bottomSlope*self.bottomMinX + self.bottomIntercept))
    def GetCenterLineRightCorner(self):
        if self.contour is None or len(self.randomPoinsInCnt) == 0:
            return (0,0)    
        # calc via via y = m*x + b with max
        return (int(self.bottomMaxX), int(self.bottomSlope*self.bottomMaxX + self.bottomIntercept))
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, ContourFacts):
            return self.uid == other.uid
        return False
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.uid)



#calc mean area size from area size
vectorOfAreaSize = np.array([cv2.contourArea(cnt) for cnt in contourList])
meanAreaSize = np.mean(vectorOfAreaSize)
print("mean area size: ", meanAreaSize)
stdDevAreaSize = np.std(vectorOfAreaSize)
print("std dev area size: ", stdDevAreaSize)
thresoldDiffAreaSize = stdDevAreaSize/4
#we iterate all contours and select by ratio and size
for cnt in contourList:
    #construct helper class instance
    contourFactObj = ContourFacts(cnt)
    #calc abs diff to mean area size
    diffArea = abs(cv2.contourArea(cnt) - meanAreaSize)
    if contourFactObj.ratioHeightoWidth < ratioThresholdHeightToWidth and diffArea < (thresoldDiffAreaSize):
        contourSelectedByRatio.append(contourFactObj)

#debug print 
if DEBUGMODE:
    #we print words
    imgContourSelection = img.copy() 
    for cnt in contourSelectedByRatio:
        contourColor = randomColor()
        imgContourSelection = drawCountourOn(imgContourSelection,[cnt.contour],contourColor)
        #we print centroid 
        cv2.circle(imgContourSelection, cnt.centoird, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        p1 = cnt.GetCenterLineLeftCorner()
        p2 = cnt.GetCenterLineRightCorner()
        if p1 != (0,0) or p2 != (0,0):
            cv2.circle(imgContourSelection, p1, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
            cv2.circle(imgContourSelection, p2, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
            cv2.line(imgContourSelection, p1, p2, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imwrite("img04contourSelection.jpg",resizeImageByPercentage(imgContourSelection,30))


## E) merge all wordcontours which are neighbours to linecontours (outer middle line points are close together)  
#define distance function, differences in height is negativ weighted
def euclidianDistanceWithNegativHeightWeight(cnt1,cnt2,negativeHeightWeight=2.0):
    if cnt1 is None or cnt2 is None:
        return 1000000
    if not isinstance(cnt1, ContourFacts) or not isinstance(cnt2, ContourFacts):
        return 1000000
    p1 = cnt1.GetCenterLineRightCorner()
    p2 = cnt2.GetCenterLineLeftCorner()
    return math.sqrt((p2[0] - p1[0])**2 + (negativeHeightWeight*(p2[1] - p1[1]))**2)

# helper class to group contours
class ContourGroup:
    def __init__(self):
        self.uuid = uuid.uuid4()
        self.contourList = list()
    def GetLastElement(self):
        if len(self.contourList) == 0:
            return None
        return self.contourList[-1]
    def Add(self,cnt):
        self.contourList.append(cnt)   
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, ContourGroup):
            return self.uuid == other.uuid
        return False
    
groupMap = dict()
lineGroupList = list()
## we grouping the contours to lines
maxDistanceThresholNextWord= medianWordHigh *0.9 #TODO get better estimate
#recursive function to get nearest neighbors
def getNearestNeighbors(cnt1,depthCounter,contourSelectedByRatio,maxDistanceThresholNextWord):
    maxDepth = 10 #var for max recursion depth 
    nearestCnt = None
    nearestDist = maxDistanceThresholNextWord
    for j in range(0,len(contourSelectedByRatio)):
        cnt2 = contourSelectedByRatio[j]
        if cnt1 == cnt2:#skip same
            continue
        dist = euclidianDistanceWithNegativHeightWeight(cnt1,cnt2)
        if dist < nearestDist:
            nearestDist = dist
            nearestCnt = cnt2
    if nearestCnt is not None:#call recursive
        nearaestListWeHave = [nearestCnt] #new list
        depthCounter += 1
        if depthCounter < maxDepth:# all to call
            nearListWeGet =getNearestNeighbors(nearestCnt,depthCounter,contourSelectedByRatio,maxDistanceThresholNextWord)
            if nearListWeGet is None:
                return nearaestListWeHave
            else:
                nearListWeGet.extend(nearaestListWeHave)   
                return nearListWeGet
        else:#limit reached of recursion skip
            return nearaestListWeHave
    else:      
        return None
## E) merge all wordcontours which are neighbours to linecontours (outer middle line points are close together)      
#we group all contours
for i in range(0,len(contourSelectedByRatio)):
    cnt1 = contourSelectedByRatio[i]
    if cnt1 in groupMap:
        continue
    lineGroup = ContourGroup()
    lineGroup.Add(cnt1)
    groupMap[cnt1] = lineGroup
    depthCounter = 0
    nearaestList = getNearestNeighbors(cnt1,depthCounter,
                                       contourSelectedByRatio,maxDistanceThresholNextWord)
    if nearaestList is None:
        lineGroupList.append(lineGroup) #no neighbor found
        continue
    for cnt in nearaestList:
        groupMap[cnt] = lineGroup
        lineGroup.Add(cnt)
    lineGroupList.append(lineGroup)

if DEBUGMODE:
    imgContourGroup = img.copy()
    for group in lineGroupList:
        #print(f"group({group.uuid} size: {len(group.contourList)}")
        #we print all corner points
        for cnt in group.contourList:
            leftCorner = cnt.GetCenterLineLeftCorner()
            rigthCorner = cnt.GetCenterLineRightCorner()
            cv2.circle(imgContourGroup, leftCorner, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
            cv2.circle(imgContourGroup, rigthCorner, 5, (140, 0, 0), -1)
        #we print estimated underlines
        for cnt in group.contourList:
            leftCorner = cnt.GetCenterLineLeftCorner()
            rigthCorner = cnt.GetCenterLineRightCorner()
            cv2.line(imgContourGroup, leftCorner, rigthCorner, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        # we print all contours
        groupColor = randomColor()
        cntList = [cnt.contour for cnt in group.contourList]
        imgContourGroup = drawCountourOn(imgContourGroup,cntList,groupColor)
    cv2.imwrite("img05contourGroup.jpg",resizeImageByPercentage(imgContourGroup,30))

## F) do polynomial regression 2nd order to estimate middle line of linecontours
# calc line from stable group points
minAmountRegressionElements = 12
movingWindowSize = 3
letterCenterOffset = medianWordHigh * 0.5
lineListCollection = list()
for group in lineGroupList:
    stablePoints = list()
    for cnt in group.contourList:
        stablePoints.extend(cnt.randomPoinsInCnt)
    if len(stablePoints) >= minAmountRegressionElements :
        xValues = [x for x,y in stablePoints]
        yValues = [y for x,y in stablePoints]
        # perform polynomial regression of degree 2
        coefffientValues = np.polyfit(np.array(xValues), np.array(yValues), 2)
        # create a polynomial function with the coefficients
        polynomial = np.poly1d(coefffientValues)
        #we filter to build something like a line
        xValuesNewLineFilter = list()
        xMin =int( min(xValues))
        xMax = int(max(xValues))
        for xNew in range(xMin,xMax,movingWindowSize):
                xValuesNewLineFilter.append(xNew)
        #we predict new points with all old x values
        yValuesNew = polynomial(xValuesNewLineFilter)
        yValuesNewHighCorrect =np.array(yValuesNew) + letterCenterOffset
        lineList = list()
        #we create a list of points
        for i in range(0,len(xValuesNewLineFilter)):
            pointInt = (int(xValuesNewLineFilter[i]),int(yValuesNewHighCorrect[i]))
            lineList.append(pointInt)
        lineListCollection.append(lineList)
## G) write the lines 
imgLines = img.copy()
for lineList in lineListCollection:
    p1 = lineList[0]
    for j in range(1,len(lineList)):
        p2 = lineList[j]
        #cv2.circle(imgLines, p2Int, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.line(imgLines, p1, p2, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        p1 = p2
cv2.imwrite("img06Lines.jpg",resizeImageByPercentage(imgLines,30))

if DEBUGMODE:
    cv2.waitKey(0)

more debug output is:



The picture below shows word contours with green middle lines and red outer points for neighborhood analysis.



You're close to the end! Just(!) fit curves using 'spline interpolation' for instance.

Wow, thank you so much! I'm checking it.

Your solution seems to work, but it involves a lot of code and is a bit difficult to follow. You could improve your answer by providing explanations of your approach.

yes @stateMachine the code structure ended up to be little bit complicated, more explanation, docu and structure could improve the solution

@JoyfulWasp Hello sir, I am an amature here, but I think you are talking about dewarping the curled page here. Can you explain how to do that from the code? Thank you.

@Lusypher At the time my point of view was a bit simplistic. This is not a "simple" problem of interpolation between the coordinates of the words but a typographic problem. It is not only a question of identifying each word individually, but also each sentence, each paragraph, each title, ... Otherwise we get absurd jumps in the drawing of the baseline as we can see in the image above.

I can give you another approach, it is shorter but @t2solve's code may give you better result. Here is the method:

Otsu Threshold the image, close with a custom kernel that connects horizontal blobs
Find contours of each word in text and add their star&end points to a list
Extract all the lines in the text by grouping words that are on the same line
Fit a polygon to the points in each line

This is thresholded image:

This is closed image with the custom kernel:

This is te poly fitted image with baselines:

This is the result for your other image:

Here is the complete code:
import cv2
import numpy
import math

#Funciton to create custom kernel
def xAxisKernel(size):
    size = size if size%2 else size+1
    xkernel = numpy.zeros((size,size),dtype=numpy.uint8)
    center = size//2
    for j in range(size):
        xkernel[center][j] = 1
        xkernel[center-1][j] = 1
        xkernel[center+1][j] = 1
    return xkernel

#Put each word inside a line
def extractLines(words):
    lines = []
    while len(words):
        line = []
        line.append(words[0][0]) #add a word to a line
        line.append(words[0][1]) #add a word to a line
        line_start,line_end = words[0][0],words[0][1]
        
        words.remove(words[0])
        for ww in line:
            for word in words:
                start,end = word
                if math.dist(line_end,start) < 100 and abs(line_end[1]-start[1])<30 and line_end[0]<start[0]:
                    line_end = end
                    line.append([word[0][0],word[0][1]+3])
                    line.append([word[1][0],word[1][1]+3])
                    words.remove(word)
                if math.dist(line_start,end) < 100 and abs(line_start[1]-end[1])<30 and line_start[0]>end[0]:
                    line_start = start
                    line.append([word[0][0],word[0][1]+3])
                    line.append([word[1][0],word[1][1]+3])
                    words.remove(word)
        lines.append(line)
    
    return lines

image = cv2.imread('curved_book.jpg')
h,w,c = image.shape
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,xAxisKernel(13)) #Connecting the letters of a word

contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closed,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#From contours extract start and end points of each word
words = [] #list to contain start and end point of each word
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area>500 and area<20000:

        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = numpy.intp(box)
        box = [[p[0],p[1]] for p in box]
        box.sort()    
        start = box[0] if box[0][1]>box[1][1] else box[1]
        end = box[2] if box[2][1]>box[3][1] else box[3]
        word = [start,end]
        words.append(word)



lines = extractLines(words) # list that contains start-end points of every word in each line
lines = [numpy.array(line,numpy.int32) for line in lines]

#Draw baselines
for line in lines:
    #side parabola coeffs
    coeffs = numpy.polyfit(line[:,0], line[:,1], 2)
    poly = numpy.poly1d(coeffs)


    line_start_x = min(line[:,0])
    line_end_x = max(line[:,0])
    xarr = numpy.arange(line_start_x, line_end_x)
    yarr = poly(xarr)

    parab_pts = numpy.array([xarr, yarr],dtype=numpy.int32).T
    cv2.polylines(image, [parab_pts], False, (255,0,0), 8)
    for p in line:
        cv2.circle(image,p,10,(0,0,255),-1)


cv2.imshow('thresh',cv2.resize(thresh,(w*720//h,720)))
cv2.imshow('closed',cv2.resize(closed,(w*720//h,720)))
cv2.imshow('image',cv2.resize(image,(w*720//h,720)))
cv2.waitKey()

When grouping the words to extract the lines the idea is:

Choose a word remove it from the main list and add it to a fresh line list

Set chosen word's start point as line_start, its end point as line_end

Check remaining words.

Compare their start points with line_end.
If they are close and on the same y-level add that word to line
Also remove that word from words list
Change the line_end as the added word's end point


Do the above process for the line_start

On the remaining words repeat the full process to find another line



Possible improvements: for filtering you may divide the source image into pieces threshold them with otsu seperately and combine them, this way the effect of varying light will be reduced.
Possible issue: sometimes if there are smal words close to each other (like 'to a car') one of the words may be skipped.
